# Getting the error: getAddress is not a function

Tags: hardhat, testing

I am running tests in hardhat and trying to get the contract deployed in the testing environment.

Here is the code I am using:

```
const { assert, expect } = require("chai");
const { deployments, ethers, getNamedAccounts } = require("hardhat");

describe("FundMe", async function () {
    let fundMe;
    let deployer
    let mockV3Aggregator;
    beforeEach(async () => {
        deployer = (await getNamedAccounts()).deployer;
        await deployments.fixture(["all"]);
        const FundMe = await deployments.get("FundMe");
        fundMe = await ethers.getContractAt(FundMe.abi, FundMe.getAddress());
        const MockV3Aggregator = await deployments.get("MockV3Aggregator");
        mockV3Aggregator = await ethers.getContractAt(
            MockV3Aggregator.abi,
            MockV3Aggregator.getAddress()
        );
    });
    
    describe("constructor", async function () {
        it("sets the aggregator addresses correctly", async function () {
            const response = await fundMe.getPriceFeed();
            assert.equal(response, mockV3Aggregator.address);
        })
    })
```

And I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: FundMe.getAddress is not a function
```

I was originally using FundMe.address instead of FundMe.getAddress() but I was still getting a similar error saying .address is not a function. I am very confused about how to get the address for the contract. Please help me.

Comment: have you tried logging FundMe to help debug what functions or attributes exist?

Answer (score 0):

getAddress is not a function, you have to use

```
FundMe.address
```

Comment: this is in ethers v6, in v5 getAddress() should work

Answer (score 0):

once you create the instance of the contract, add:

```
const contract = new ethers.Contract(Address, abi, provider);
```

if you run the script and do

```
conole.log(contract);
```

it will return something like this:

```
Contract {
  target: '0xA2b4C0Af19cC16a6CfAcCe81F192B024d625817D',
  interface: Interface {
    fragments: [ [EventFragment] ],
    deploy: ConstructorFragment {
      type: 'constructor',
      inputs: [],
      payable: false,
      gas: null
    },
    fallback: null,
    receive: false
  },
  runner: JsonRpcProvider {},
  filters: {},
  fallback: null,
  [Symbol(_ethersInternal_contract)]: {}
}
```

in the target key you will find the contract address.

run:

```
console.log(contract.target);
```

Answer (score 0):

**check it out my answer here in github**

```
https://github.com/smartcontractkit/full-blockchain-solidity-course-js/discussions/5327#discussioncomment-8641263
```